# Writing a cross platform GUI/service

Tags: qt, windows-services, cross-platform, daemon

I'm working on a project that requires a desktop client to scan certain directories on a users computer at set intervals. My plan is to separate the actual directory scanning code out of the GUI and into a service so that it can run even when the GUI isn't open. Does this sound like the right way to do this? Additionally I'd like all this to be cross platform. I'm using QT to create the GUI. Is it possible to write cross platform services? I've looked into QTService a bit. The documentation for QTService says it's for `implementing Windows services and Unix daemons`. I assume the Unix portion means support for both linux and mac systems? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ,Qt definitely seems a good option for developing cross platform applications.You can write once and recompile it for windows ,Mac and linux.A Qt app will actually look like a native app because it uses the native look and feel to decorate its widgets.
You can alter the build process to build a GUI app or a console application that can be invoked from commandline.

**EDIT**
QtService is not part of the standard SDK . It is available [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/trees/master/qtservice)

Comment: The provided link is no longer alive. https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice